# How to add onclick event on image dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating images with `onclick` properties dynamically using jQuery

```
 function create() {
     divElem    = $("<div class='row'>");
     $('#bankList').append(divElem);
     elem = $("<div class='col-sm-3', style='height:110px'>");
     image = $("<img style=' max-width:90%'>");
     var imageFile = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/' + prop[j];
     image.attr('src', imageFile);
     image.attr('id',prop[j]);
     image.on("click",submitForm(this.id));
     elem.append(image);
     divElem.prepend(elem);
 }
```

Function `create` is called on `winodw.onload` and `submit form` gets called `onload` only. It should be called on clicking of image

Comment: *"...submit form gets called onload only"* Do you mean `submitForm()`? If so, I don't see in the code provided where `submitForm()` is actually called before images being clicked. In your code, the only way that `submitForm()` is executed is if an image is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Your event handler is wrong. You could provide an anonymous handler function instead:

```
image.on("click",function() {
  submitForm(this.id);
});
```

See details in [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method documentation.

Comment: $("image") better no?

Comment: It's actually: `image.on("click", function() { submitForm(this.id) });` because the variable `image` is already a jQuery Object.

Comment: woah wait so if i write `var image = ... ` i'll override a default var?

Answer (score 1):

you can add img onClick function on document

```
$(document).on('click', 'img', function() {
    alert('Click on Image id: '+$(this).attr('id'));
});
```